# SVD and intrinsic categorization

Tags: embeddings

I just recently got interested in Data Science, and just encountered concepts such as embedding from high dimensions to low dimensions. Maybe on an irrelevant note, but in this video: [Geometry of Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) | Lê Nguyên Hoang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQbbsKK1kus), he mentioned that we can think of SVD as mapping of movies into concepts and mapping of users into concepts. Furthermore, he also mentioned that such concepts are to be data-driven. That makes me wonder if the theorem of SVD imply that there exists intrinsic categorizations of data.

Can someone give me any analysis on why this might be true or false ? Also it would be appreciated if you can appeal to intuitions, since I am very new to this area.

**Edit** The url was corrected, i mistook it for another video